# Add or remove class from all li's in an unordered list except the current li with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

Here is my HTML structure

```
<ul class="checklist">
    <li class="opaque"><a href="">Link</a></li>
    <li class="transparent"><a href="">Link</a></li>
    <li class="transparent"><a href="">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

When I click the anchor within one of the transparent li's I want to set it to `opaque` and all the other li's within the ul to `transparent`.

Any ideas on how to do this efficiently?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$('document').ready( function(){
  $('ul.checklist').find('a').click( function(){
    $(this)
      .parent().addClass('opaque').removeClass('transparent')
      .siblings().addClass('transparent').removeClass('opaque');
  });
});
```

But if you're really only representing two states that never occur together, why not just use one class, the absence of which represents the second state? Then you'd have this:

```
$('document').ready( function(){
  $('ul.checklist').find('a').click( function(){
    $(this)
      .parent().addClass('opaque')
      .siblings().removeClass('opaque');
  });
});
```

Comment: +1 for point of about 2 states; I'd also suggest using `closest` with `find` (instead of `parent`), or not using `find`. I recommend applying recursion consistently (i.e. everywhere or no where) in cases like this

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$('.checklist a').click(function(){ 
    $(this).closest('li') // get current LI
       .removeClass('transparent')
       .addClass('opaque')
       .siblings() // get adjacent LIs
         .removeClass('opaque')
         .addClass('transparent');
});
```

Comment: better selector would be `.checklist > li > a` otherwise `li` is redundant

Answer (score 0):

How about this solution:

```
$("li.transparent a").bind("click", function(){
    $("ul.checklist li").attr("class", "transparent");
    $(this).parent().attr("class", "opaque");
});
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `addClass`/`removeClass` instead of `attr`. The code is simpler and handles other cases (e.g. multiple classes unrelated to the problem at hand)

Comment: @Micheal Usually I use add/removeClass but in this case I thought that in this case removing all css classes could be more useful.